# docker-compose portmapping gives failed to create endpoint hnsCall failed in Win32: The specified port already exists

Tags: docker-compose

I have started a new (.net core 3.0)project in Visual Studio, with Docker support (Windows)

I have added Docker support (right-click on project Add->Docker support) and in the same way added Docker compose support.

If I just Click "play-button" for Docker Compose, the project starts everything works well.

But when I run **docker-compose up** from the solution folder I get

> Cannot start service testproj30: failed to create endpoint
>   testproj30_testproj30_1 on network nat: hnsCall failed in Win32: The
>   specified port already exists.

(I have closed my VS solution). If I remove the port mapping in docker-compose.override.yaml I dont get this error message. I have dont the most common tricks with restarting docker servce, hni service and so on. Nothing helps.

I dont want to depend on all VS-voodoo from the project file and God knows what other files that are involved.

I can run **docker run -p 8080:80 443:443** without any port problems

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a similar problem by removing some terminated container and then pruning networks.

List terminated container :

```
docker ps -a
```

Remove them (Cygwin syntax) :

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

You will have error message for runnnig containers.

Clean your networks :

```
docker network prune
```

For myself, the main cause was the Docker killing process skiped the port releasing mechanism of my application.

Comment: Hi Karbos, thanks for your reply. Tested both, didnt work for me, I get the exact same result

Comment: Maybe you have to kill some docker container launched by VS : `docker kill $(docker ps -aq) && docker rm $(docker ps -aq) && docker network prune`

Comment: If you reboot and then launch docker-compose with CLI you don't have any problem, do you ?

Comment: No, it doesnt :(. I have restarted my computer numerous times during this process.

Comment: On the other hand, you might be right.. As of now, the only port that survived a restart was a 5672 and thats was due to a local rabbitmq-server...

Comment: Tell me if that fix the endpoint problem under Windows for you. I really think there is a problem with the docker-compose killing container strategy under Windows...